# can we do functional verification using JasperGold?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

can anybody tell me how to do functional verification using JasperGold?. 
I am new to this tool.

Answer (score 1):

JasperGold is a formal verification tool. Functional verification is normally done using simulation and functional coverage.

The input to a formal tool is you design plus a set of ASSUME properties. The ASSUME properties typically limit the legal range of the input stimuli.
Given the input the formal tool can prove other properties.

E.g. if your design is a full adder and you set ASSUME properties that the inputs are between 0 and 5. The formal too should be able to prove that the output is always between 0 and 10. It should also be able to prove that the output is always equal to the sum of the inputs. This last property can be seen as 'functional verification'. You have verified that you HDL code and your property are functionally equal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please tell me can we use makefile and print topology? or this is only formal verification tool?

Comment: Okay you mean to say using "formal application" we can perform functional verification. That is using assume property.

Comment: @Trupti I would suggest reading up on functional verification before posting on here

Comment: why? what is wrong in my question? I am new to jaspergold so only I am asking questions. This website is for helping people who are struggling in some area write?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can perform functional verification using JasperGold.  JasperGold is a formal property checking tool.

Functional verification is the process of verifying the functionality of a design.  Traditional simulation (directed or random) can be used to perform functional verification.  Formal property checking tools perform functional verification.  There are also formal equivalence checking tools (like Hector from Synopsys) which perform functional verification.

There are a number of formal tools which do not perform functional verification.  For instance Formality.

To use JasperGold you need to create properites using a property checking language.  SystemVerilog Assertions (or SVA) are the industry standard now.  You can download the (surprisingly readable) SystemVerilog LRM from the Internet.